# Python Selenium trying to click a button that is next to a username

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create a test to delete a user. To do this I need to click a delete button which is located to the left of each username.
The delete button comes before the username in the code, this makes creating the xpath for it more difficult (for me)

Here is the page source for the username and delete button:

```
<div class="user-list-item">
 <div>
  <span class="delete">
   <span class="icon-dash"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="username" title="username">username</span>
  <span title="Change password" class="edit"><span class="icon-edit"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preceding` or `preceding-sibling` in xpath to locate the note before context node.

You can evaluate like following :

```
//span[@title='username'][text()='username']/preceding::span[@class='delete']
```